# Cannot scandir() correct directory after htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, scandir

On /portfolio.php (which is located on root of the site) I want to show all images from the directory /trabajos/tataviajes.

```
foreach(scandir('./trabajos/tataviajes/', 1) as $filename){
     echo '<img src="'.$filename.'"/>';
 }
```

The function open the images like this: /portfolio/123.jpg instead of /trabajos/tataviajes/123.jpg

The htaccess code that I think it might interfere is:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(\w+)/?$ portfolio.php?i=$1
```

Was I clear? What is the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scandir` returns an array of **filenames** not *file paths* see http://php.net/scandir#refsect1-function.scandir-returnvalues

You need to prefix the path to the filename. Consider something like:

```
$directory = 'trabajos/tataviajes/';
foreach(scandir($directory, 1) as $filename){
    echo '<img src="/'.$directory.$filename.'"/>';
}
```

also, [consider using `htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) so special characters in the path will not mess up your markup:

```
echo '<img src="'.htmlentities('/'.$directory.$filename).'"/>';
```

Comment: @GuillermoDelicia no problem! also, use `var_dump` to see the var variable contents and object structures, e.g. `var_dump($filename)` or `var_dump(scandir('./trabajos/tataviajes/',1))` that should help you diagnose problems in the future ;)